# Dataset where nodes sometimes have multiple parents, how can I display it in a tree-like manner? (d3.js or something similiar)

Tags: javascript, layout, graph, d3.js, tree

[image]

I have a dataset similar to the image above and I also want to present it similar to how it's done in the image, basically it's nodes with multiple parents.

So far I've been using d3.js and displaying it with a [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout), so it's displayed something like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 , but I want it displayed more like this: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html but where nodes can have multiple parents instead of just one.

Is that possible d3.js? And if not, what I can I use?

Also, does such a graph have a name?

Comment: If you have the node positions, you can use D3 directly. If you need to compute them based on the child-parent relationships, you'll have to implement your own layout to do this.

Comment: @01AutoMonkey did you ever succeed at this? It seems to me like Sankey is not the answer you were looking for. I would like to do something more like your photo.

Comment: @RobertKuykendall I ended up using dagre, see: https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre , https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3 , and https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3/wiki#demos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sankey diagram](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/) layout might be what you are looking for. You can find the source code 
[on github](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/sankey).

One improvement you can make to have the diagram look more like a tree is to change the size of the links in order to have lines.

The diagram looks like this in the end: 
[image: Sankey diagram]